# Ограниченные символы в input при вводе

Tags: javascript, html

Добрый День! Столкнулся с проблемой ограничения на ввод символов в поле input для номера телефона. Имею скрипт, который позволяет ввести только цифры в данное поле, но есть ли возможность сделать допустимым не только цифры, а символы:

> +, - , (space), ()

Заранее спасибо, свой код прикрепил ниже:

```js
function isNumberKey(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;
  return true;
};
```

```html
Enter you number:
<input v-model="phone" type="text" maxlength="22" onkeyup="validate(this)" v-validate="'required|alpha_spaces'" data-vv-as="Telefono" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('phone') }">
```

Comment: Можно поправить условие if и добавить туда нужные коды символов. http://www.ascii.cl/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ссылайтесь на [ASCII таблицу](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp)

```js
function isNumberKey(evt) {
  
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  if (charCode != 32 && charCode != 40 && charCode != 41 && charCode != 43 && charCode != 45 && charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) 
    return false;
  return true;
};
```

```html
Enter you number:
<input v-model="phone" type="text" maxlength="22" onkeyup="validate(this)" v-validate="'required|alpha_spaces'" data-vv-as="Telefono" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('phone') }">
```

Answer (score 2):

Возьмите лучше уже готовый для этого плагин maskedinput. По умолчанию он позволяет задавать маски для ввода символы/цифры/символы+цифры, но можно задавать и свои с помощью $.mask.definitions[e] = '[0-9a-zA-Z+-]' и тут уже указываете допустимые символы. А использовать будете в виде $('.mask').mask('+7 (eee) eee-ee-ee') Хотя я для ввода телефона использую просто маску +7 (999) 999-99-99 где на месте 9ок позволяет указывать любые цифры

Comment: Я думал над этим, но там только сделать можно для конкретной страны форму телефона, а мне worldwide хотелось бы иметь, то есть в свободной форме как человек желает, будь оно +1394472852, то + 1-4828-4324 и в таком роде. То есть свободный ввод огранич. символов.

Comment: @Oleg Severnuy, То же самое, только регулярку изменить

Comment: тогда проще загуглите ввод телефона с выбором страны - давненько я находил подобный скрипт, но уже не помню где - там можно было выбрать страну и маска сразу под нее подгонялась. Ваша задача широко распространенная, поэтому проще найти уже готовый плагин нежели писать свой.

Comment: @Vladimir Novopashin, быстро вы сдались) Почему бы не дописать до чего-то типа `\+?[\d\-\(\) ]+`